# Access two directories using httpd.conf on same domain

Tags: php, laravel, apache, phpmyadmin, httpd.conf

How can I configure httpd.conf to access `laravelapp` and `phpmyadmin` in below way:

```
http://something.com
```

Wants to access laravel app,

```
http://something.com/phpmyadmin
```

to access phpmyadmin.

Directories `laravelapp` and `phpmyadmin` in `/var/www/html`

I did below code in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, but not working.

```
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravelapp/public"

   #
   # Relax access to content within /var/www.
   #
   <Directory "/var/www/html/laravelapp">
       AllowOverride All
       # Allow open access:
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Laravel app `/public` dir contains default `.htaccess` file as comes with laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Your phpadmin installation is outside the `DocumentRoot` so you need something else. You can either:

- Create a symlink to the PMA installation (you'll need `Options +FollowSymlinks` for this which you should have, since `All` is the default).
- Use [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias). You just need to add the following to your current config:

  `Alias "phpmyadmin" "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin"`